# JS: Download zip file from a string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to receive a zip file as a string from an Ajax request and then hold it in memory so it can be downloaded multiple times if necessary so that only the one request is sent.

I tried to download it with this:

```
zip_string = 'PK etc.'

function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("zip1.zip", zip_string);
```

It came through as a zip but then there was obviously a problem because it wouldn't open. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should create a blob url instead of creating a base64 str, using [URL.createObjectURL(blob)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem by encoding the zip file string as base64 on the server before it gets sent through.

```
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    bytes = f.read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes)
```

And then in the JS I just specify that it's base64:

```
zip_string = 'UEsDBBQAAAAIANQzCU0J56mLPAIAAD4VAAAOAAAA etc.'

function download(filename, data) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;base64,' + data);
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("zip1.zip", zip_string);
```

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to download the zip without base64 encoding it. By specifying the correct Blob type?

Answer (score 2):

Using JSZip package: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

```
public async downloadFile(filename: string, content: string) {
        const zip = new JSZip();
        await zip.loadAsync(content, {base64: true});
        const blob = await zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"});

        const element = document.createElement("a");
        element.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        element.setAttribute("download", filename);
        element.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }


const fileName = "test.zip";
const content = "UEsDBAoAAAAAAI5ONE9i6ZVwCQAAAAkAAAAIAAAAdGVzdC50eHRUZXN0IGZpbGVQSwECPwAKAAAAAACOTjRPYumVcAkAAAAJAAAACAAkAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAdGVzdC50eHQKACAAAAAAAAEAGABz76T2f2/VAXPvpPZ/b9UB1NBncjhp1QFQSwUGAAAAAAEAAQBaAAAALwAAAAAA"; // base64 content without mimeType

this.downloadFile(fileName, content);
```

Comment: This is an amazing library!

Answer (score 1):

The data type of your link's `href` is plain text (ie as specified by `data:text/plain`) which basically means, the contents of the link will be treated by the browser as plain text.

A zip archive is a binary format - you will need to do a bit more work to generate a real zip file and then cache it client side, in this way. You may want to look at [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) as a library to help you with this.

You can however make a simple change to get the download function working - just change `"zip1.zip"` to `"zip1.txt"`. I've prepared a [jsFiddle here if you](https://jsfiddle.net/96bq407d/5/) to see this in action.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I want an actual .zip file to be downloadable, not a .txt file